# How to use setInterval() inside for loop on a list of images

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm currently trying to sequence a number of images, changing the opacity of each image incrementally, in order to create an animation.

Currently, it's jumping to the last image each time and skipping all the other images.

My code is as follows:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  (function(i) {
    setInterval(function() {
      images[i].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 500)
  })(i);
}
```

```css
.sequenceImage {
  opacity: .5
}
```

```html
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image1" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image2" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image3" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image4" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image5" /><br>
```

Comment: I think better than using Javascript might be to use CSS transitions for the opacity. https://davidwalsh.name/css-transitions

Comment: Also no need for interval since you do not toggle the opacity

Comment: You are creating one interval per element. I doubt that is what you meant to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few things here:

1. `function(i)` change `i` to some other name to make is distinct and remove any confusion for future devs
2. Then instead of `setInterval` use `setTimeout` as you will set the `opacity` one time only.
3. Then finally multiply index to `setTimeout` delay to add the fade-in effect.

Demo:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByClassName("sequenceImage");

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  (function(idx) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      images[idx].style.opacity = 1;
    }, 500 * (idx + 1))
  })(i);
}
```

```css
.sequenceImage {opacity: .5; transition: opacity 0.4s;margin-right:10px}
body{display:flex}
```

```html
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image1" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image2" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image3" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image4" /><br>
<img class="sequenceImage" src="https://via.placeholder.com/50/0000FF/808080?Text=image5" /><br>
```